# Only one record in plugin

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller

I have a question. Is it possible for only one record to be created in the plugin? So in the backend, when I click on the backend menu, I get a form and not a list of records.
If I click on side bakend menu "Fakty" on picture then I need it to be displayed only form. No list of records. 
[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJdKp.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please add some more details

Comment: I think this question is so niche that you might have better luck asking directly in the OctoberCMS forum (https://octobercms.com/forum)

Comment: Yes I did this but I want try here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by **Setting** module of Octobercms.

Please read this documentation for that.

https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/settings#writing-settings